# Django models: form with infinite group of fields repetition

Tags: python, django

I'm studying django these days and I need your help to find a solution to this problem about form construction.

Let's say I have an entity called 'Activity' just made up by:

```
- title: just a char field
- ActivityYears: a couple of start-end years that can be repeated multiple times
```

ActivityYears is made up by:

```
- start year
- end year
```

That's how my database should look like:

```
activity_table
-ID
-title

activity_years_table
-year start
-year end
-activity ID
```

That's how it looks like front-end

```
Activity title 1
2001 - 2003
2005 - 2006
2007 - 2010

Activity title 2
2011 - 2013
2015 - 2016

and so on
```

I'd dare to say that Activity and ActivityYears are models but I cannot connect them in a proper way. When I add an Activity item I should be able to add as many start-end years as I need but how?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely want to use two separate models with a `Foreign Key` relationship. For example:

```
class Activity(Model):
    id = AutoField(editable=False, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = CharField(default="Activity")

class ActivityYear(Model):
    id = AutoField(editable=False, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    year_start = IntegerField(default=1900)
    year_end = IntegerField(default=1999)

    activity_id = ForeignKey(Activity)
```

With this model design, we can define that each `ActivityYear` had a member `activity_id` which points to the `id` field of a valid `Activity` row in the database. With this information, you would be able to select `ActivityYear` objects from the database using the respective `Activity` object's `id` member:

`SELECT * FROM activity_years WHERE activity_id = 1`

or in Django:

`activity_years = Activity.objects.filter(activity_id=1)`

In order to add `ActivityYear` objects which map to a specific `Activity` object, you can use the following:

```
ActivityYear.objects.create({
    'year_start': 1990,
    'year_end': 1999,
    'activity_id': 1,
})
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanx Michael, that was exactly what I needed!